# How to map a Keyboard Entry in Java Swing to another Character or String?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, keystroke

I want to trap a key or combination of keys (say ‘b’, Shift-b, Alt-b, and Shift-Alt-b) that is input into the keyboard for a Java Swing application. I want to do this for each of the keys on the keyboard. Once the key is trapped, I want to replace it with another character or string of my choice, and display the substitute character or string in a JTextPane object, at the same location in the JTextPane where the original character was typed.

The idea is to map the keys of a normal QWERTY keyboard to the characters of another script and language, like Hindi.

I am able to trap the keys of the QWERTY keyboard just fine, using the following kind of code:

```
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
KeyStroke key = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('b');

InputMap inputMap = textPane.getInputMap();
inputMap.put(key, DefaultEditorKit.forwardAction);
```

However for the InputMap, I am only able to substitute the KeyStroke for another “Action” like DefaultEditorKit.forwardAction, not another character or String. I don’t necessarily have to use an InputMap - any method that allows me to map a keyboard entry to another character or String would be fine.

Thanks,
Sandeep

Comment: Crossposted: http://www.coderanch.com/t/658968/GUI/java/map-Keyboard-Entry-Java-Swing

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the `DefaultKeyTypedAction` from the class `DefaultEditorKit` to see how you can bind your keys.